# О расстановке запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Желательно подробно... Почему запятая ставится?

*Небо по-прежнему сияло голубизной, и всё же там (,) на блестящей поверхности моря, что-то темнело.*

Answer (score 1):

Уточненяющее обстоятельство места. Где? – там. Где именно? – *на блестящей поверхности моря*.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm

§96. Уточняющие члены предложения